# Getting SQS queue name or URL from ARN, or check a queue exists by ARN

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

The AWS documentation states consistently that ARNs should not be constructed programmatically from names or URLs, because the way those strings are constructed is not guaranteed to be constant in time.

My issue is that, on SQS, the RedrivePolicy attribute returned by [GetQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html) references the dead-letter queue by ARN only.

I am currently writing a service to create queues and set them up, or verify that their setup is correct if they already exist. But I don't see the way I can verify that the dead-letter queue ARN matches an existing queue, unless I do parse it to get the name. Is there a way around that?

(actually to be fair, there is one way that respects the "don't parse ARNs programmatically" rule, which consists in calling [ListQueues](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ListQueues.html) then loop through the resulting URLs calling [GetQueueAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_GetQueueAttributes.html) on each, but that sounds like a silly amount of work, and could potentially fail if there are more than 1000 queues on the account, so I'm excluding doing this).

Currently looking for a solution in C# but the issue is not language-dependent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, there is a parser class in the `AWSSDK.Core` package called `Amazon.Arn`.

It was seemingly added around version 3.3.104 of the package in Dec '19 (Source [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/commits/master/sdk/src/Core/Arn.cs)). So even though ARNs aren't meant to be constructed programmatically, this seems to be setting the format in stone.

Now to get the name, knowing that the ARN is that of a queue, one can do `Arn.Parse(queueArn).Resource`.

Conversely, one can create a new Arn object then call `ToString()` on it to get the full ARN.

This of course can be improved for a random ARN (The `Arn` object contains more information than the resource sur as the service), and will not work as is for any resource type (e.g. `Resource` would return `queue-name:some-guid` for an SQS subscription, or `rule/rule-name` for an EventBridge rule.

More information can be found about ARNs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is to get the Queue URL using the ARN,

```
queue_name = queue_arn.split(':')[-1]
account_id = queue_arn.split(':')[-2]
sqs_client = boto3.client('sqs')
url = sqs_client.get_queue_url(
        QueueName=queue_name,
        QueueOwnerAWSAccountId=account_id
    )
```

And if queue exists:

```
try:
    queue = sqs_client.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=queue_name)
except:
    print("Queue doesn't exist!")
```

Comment: Is this an approach that aws has committed to supporting? I haven't seen anything about that. Seems like asking people to just trust that the format of the arn will never change.

Answer (score 0):

w/o boto

```
split_arn = queue_arn.split(":")
if len(split_arn) == 5:
    queue_name = split_arn[-1]
    account_id = split_arn[-2]
    aws_region = split_arn[-3]
    return f"https://sqs.{aws_region}.amazonaws.com/{account_id}/{queue_name}"
return None
```